# In Javascript, how do I turn a date object into a epoch timestamp?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

```
Wed, 07 Dec 2011 15:31:11 GMT
```

If I have that date object, how do I turn that into a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
var dateString = "Wed, 07 Dec 2011 15:31:11 GMT";
var mSecondsSinceEpoch = Date(dateString).getTime();
```

which returns the UNIX Epoch time in milliseconds. You can leave 'dateString' empty to take the current time. However, when a Date object is cast to a number, it will also return the above. Thus

```
var mSecondsSinceEpoch = +Date(dateString) // milliseconds
```

or

```
var secondsSinceEpoch = (Date(dateString) / 1000) // seconds
```

also works! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for more information on the Javascript Date object.

Answer (score 2):

```
var unixTimeStamp = (new Date('Wed, 07 Dec 2011 15:31:11 GMT')).getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert into a timestamp by coercing into a number, e.g. `+date`. However, this will return the amount of milliseconds.

To get the amount of seconds since epoch, you would need divide by 1000. Since dividing already involves numbers, you can eliminate the `+`:

```
Math.floor(date / 1000);   // 1000 ms = 1s
```